# How do I use separate templates with my angular directive bower package?

Tags: angularjs, bower

So I have a large set of directives I created that I want to use on many projects, so I turned it into a bower package and included it in one of my projects. Unfortunately the directives won't work, because the templateUrl path is incorrect.

The templateUrls are based on the templates being in the same directory as the js for the directives. So "./tabbedtextareas.html" What are some of my simpler options for solving this problem?

The ones I've thought of so far are:

- copy and paste the html into the JS files

  - editing the templates will be a pain afterwards
- use grunt to compile the templates with the JS, perhaps even creating a hook to commit, merge to master and push.

  - This is a very simple plugin and I prefer to keep things as simple as possible.
- put my templates in a directory, then in each project have my server handle requests to that folder.

  - anyone requiring my directives as a dependency in bower would need to do know this specific thing. Ie. the package would not installable simply by bower install.

Is there maybe like a bower install script you can add or something?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how about using grunt-usemin to update the paths?

Comment: essentially number 2. I would need to add an extra folder with my distribution files, then always remember to run grunt before pushing. Or use nodemon and deal with any potential lag from compiling every save.

It works, but it's not super ideal.

Comment: I'm doing option 3 for now, until I can find a better answer.

Comment: i think you're gonna be running grunt before pushing anyways (you'd wanna run jshint etc., wouldn't you?)

Comment: You know what I do? I program in vim, then run git commit, then git push.

I don't change my grunt config, run grunt test task, then a publish task, then have to recheck that the demo works, then push.

I keep things simple. If my project involved browserify, I would use Grunt, then consider all other possibilities of Grunt... but otherwise I don't yet have a need for it. Simplicity is the key to everything.

Comment: I think you can save your html template into your directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been on the hunt for guidance/advice on this very problem, and have considered a number of different options. I thought I'd share what I've settled on currently.

**N.B.** the project that this is approach is being used on is still in its early stages, so the approach described is by no means set in stone. I wouldn't be surprised if I had to adapt/change it in the future.

Background context is the same, we've got multiple self-contained directives living on GitHub that are used via bower. Each components template has to be inline with the directive, as `templateUrl` paths won't work.

I'm essentially doing option 2 from above, using gulp, and leveraging the angular template cache using the gulp-angular-templatecache plugin.

### Solution

#### `gulpfile.js`

Does 2 things, parse component name and write template contents to template cache (via gulp plugin) and concatenate component code and mark-up into single file (into `dist/<component-name>.js`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    templates = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    pkg = require('./package.json');

var template = 'myTemplate.tpl.html'

gulp.task('templates', function () {
  return gulp.src(template)
    .pipe(templates('templates.tmp', {
      root: '/templates/',
      module: pkg.name
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});

gulp.task('concat', ['templates'], function () {
  return gulp.src([pkg.main, 'templates.tmp'])
    .pipe(concat(pkg.name + '.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

gulp.task('clean', ['concat'], function () {
  gulp.src('./*.tmp', {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(['*.js', '*.html'], ['build']);
});

gulp.task('build', ['templates', 'concat', 'clean']);
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'watch']);
```

#### Output

The template gets set in the template cache, and the directive retrieves it via `$templateCache.get(key)` when setting the `template` attribute. This gives the single file output needed to use this component via bower, whilst allowing you to maintain the mark up in a separate file in source.

```
angular.module('myModule', []).directive('myDirective', function ($templateCache) {

  return {
    template: $templateCache.get('/template/myTemplate.tpl.html');
    link: function (scope, elm, attr) {

    }
  };
});

angular.module("myModule").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {$templateCache.put("/template/myTemplate.tpl.html","<div>This is the template for your component</div>");}]);
```

### Thoughts

1. There's an additional overhead of having a build step when working on a component. Given the requirement, I don't think there's a way to completely avoid such a step. If it's not done during component build, then it'd have to be done at implementation time. Given those 2 options, I think it's better to do it in the component when the scope is narrow and clear.
2. I'm not convinced my gulp tasks are entirely optimal. There's a certain amount of synchronicity, which runs contrary to "the gulp way". Could probably figure out how to improve it with some time/effort.

Comment: Well written. Thank you. I haven't worked on this project in a bit, but I'll probably be suring it up in a couple weeks, so I'll get back here at that time and let you know how things go.

Your answer is definitely appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I used [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates) "Grunt build task to concatenate & register your AngularJS templates in the $templateCache"

```
// within my Gruntfile.js
grunt.initConfig({
  ngtemplates: {
    'angular-my-directives': {
      src:      'views/**/*.html',
      dest:     'template.js'
    }
  }
  // ...
});
```

generates something like: `./template.js`

```
angular.module('angular-my-directives').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {

  $templateCache.put('views/directives/my-download.html',
    "<form name=\"myDownloadForm\" ng-submit=\"submit()\" novalidate>\n" +
    "</form>"
  );

}]);
```

Now in my directive I can simply use `templateUrl: 'views/directives/my-download.html'` and it will use the $templateCache.

Finally I used [grunt-contrib-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-concat) to combine my files for easy loading.

Comment: I do the same thing and provided basically the same answer for a similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34427288/2682499